# How to group by week in Entity Framework Core 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

`var byWeek = data.GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", x.Date));`
But these classes (DbFunctions and SqlFunctions are not available in Entity Framework Core) (reference).

So my question is How can I group by week in Entity Framework core 3.0?

Comment: You don't. That's a reporting query, unsuitable for ORMs like EF. The easy way is to create a [Calendar table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/) prepopulated with dates for eg the next 20 years, and extra columns for month, year, week number, day of week, quarter, semester etc, covered by indexes. Once you have that you can simply join with it on a date column and group by the `WeekNumber` or `ISOWeekNumber` columns.

Comment: That's a *lot* faster than trying to group by `DATEPART(wk,date)` as it can easily take advantage of indexes. `DATEPART` on the other hand has to scan the entire table to calculate the week number before it can start grouping

Comment: That's why reporting databases, data marts etc always have a Calendar or Date dimension table